# How to solve a "NameError" in python while with numbers is solvable but with words not?

Tags: python

I am new writing a list of names but when I want to remove a certain name that is repeated several times in the list, it gives me an error name . 
I tried with WHILE ... IN . but this works with numbers but nut names .
I don't know why ???

this one works...

```
 x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3]
 while 2 in x: x.remove(2)
 print(x)
 [1, 3, 4, 3]
```

but see...

```
 new = [ Behrad, Mohammad, Behrad, Behrad, Leyla, Bahman]
 while Behrad in new: new.remove(Behrad)
 print(new)
```

while the later code with names it gives me the below error :

```
 NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
  last)
  <ipython-input-55-c57503438675> in <module>
   ----> 1 new = [ Behrad, Mohammad, Behrad, Behrad, Leyla, Bahman]
  2 while Behrad in new: new.remove(Behrad)
  3 print(new)

  NameError: name 'Behrad' is not defined
```

I expected the name 'Behrad' being removed from the list .
thanks for any Help

Comment: Strings need to be surrounded by quotes, in all languages that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. You need to use " (quotes) to define that variable is a string. If you do not put quotes, Python understands that names given are variables and need to return their values.

This is the correct code:

```py
 new = [ "Behrad", "Mohammad", "Behrad", "Behrad", "Leyla", "Bahman"]
 while "Behrad" in new:
     new.remove("Behrad")
 print(new)
```

Comment: `Behrad` should also be quoted in the `while` loop.

Comment: when I print yours its like this : File "<ipython-input-58-5211bf93bb95>", line 2
    while "Behrad" in new: new.remove(Behrad):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Answer (score 0):

the answer I reached after surfing the net simply was :

```
def Remove(duplicate):
  final_list = []
  for num in duplicate:
    if num not in final_list:
       final_list.append(num)
  return final_list

duplicate = ["mohammad", "leyla", "behrad", "behrad", "behrad"] 
print(Remove(duplicate))
```

you can simply copy and paste my code in your jupyter notebook and see the real results...

enjoy..!